# Determiner all + uncountable noun - which of the following sentences is correct?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, determiners

All water **has** been filtered.

or

All water **have** been filtered.

?

I've already searched about this especially in youtube. From what I learned, if it's an uncountable noun after determiner all, it will be treated as singular therefore **has** should be used.

I just need a confirmation that's why I posted a question here.

Comment: What have you learned in terms of whether a countable noun is singular or plural? In the research you've done on this before asking your question, what did you find? Did you search for "uncountable noun" questions either on this site or our sibling site [ell.se]? Questions that show no effort are at risk of closure.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I feel like you’ve wasted my time, since you already knew the answer. Before you post any new questions here, I recommend you read [ask] and take the site’s [Tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncountable nouns are treated as singular:

> All water is wet.
>
> All the sand has been delivered for the playground.
>
> All life is precious.